# Editor.target vs Editor.serializedObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have this simple script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 25;

    public void PrintStuff()
    {
        Debug.Log("Stuff");
    }
}
```

And this CustomEditor where I use `Editor.serializedObject`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript))]
public class LookAtPointEditor : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty damageProp;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        // Setup the SerializedProperties.
        damageProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("damage");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(damageProp, 0, 100, new GUIContent("Damage"));

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

    }
}
```

This works fine: Undo thing works, exiting out of Play Mode works but I can do the same thing using `Editor.target` and a lot easier. And all functionality works fine with `Editor.target`. What is the purpose of `serializedObject` then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question! The [`Editor API docs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) explains this but the info is mostly scattered so I'll summarize:

For starters, there's an option [`CanEditMultipleObjects`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanEditMultipleObjects.html) which you're currently not using.  A quote form the docs:

> If this approach is used a user can select multiple assets in the
>   hierarchy window and change the values for all of them at once.

For a basic example of this, select two `GameObjects` in your scene that have the same Unity component (like `Image` or `Rigidbody`) and you'll be able to modify those components at the same time to have the same values. Most built-in components support it.

This is the first advantage using `serializedObject` will give you; it supports multi-object editing and `Editor.target` does not (you'd need [`Editor.targets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-targets.html) for that). So now if you're wondering, "*why wouldn't I just use `Editor.targets` for multi-object editing?*" consider this quote from the docs:

> Instead of modifying script variables directly, it's advantageous to
>   use the SerializedObject and SerializedProperty system to edit them,
>   since this automatically handles **multi-object editing, undo, and
>   Prefab overrides**.

What this boils down to is that if you don't want undo, prefab override, and multi-object-editing features to be automatically handled for you, just use `Editor.target` or `Editor.targets`.  If you do want those features to just work automatically, use `SerializedObject` and `SerializedProperty`.

Comment: @PetroKoval and undo, and prefab overrides, no?